# How to use an environment variable value in another environment variable name and value using dotenv?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, dotenv

For my testing framework I'm using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to read and initialize environment variables for different test environments. Now I want to use a specific environment variable value as a part of the value and the name of another environment variables.

So, I set the env var `export INSTANCE=1` before initializing the env file with `dotenv`.

This is my env file with all the env vars I want to initialize with `dotenv`:

```
# INSTANCE as part of env var value
MY_DOMAIN="http://mypage/"$INSTANCE""

# INSTANCE as part of env var name
SUBDOMAIN"$INSTANCE"="/mysubdomain"
```

And this metric is also not working:

```
# INSTANCE as part of env var value
MY_DOMAIN=http://mypage/${INSTANCE}

# INSTANCE as part of env var name
SUBDOMAIN${INSTANCE}=/mysubdomain
```

This is possible doing it via bash with

```
export MY_DOMAIN="http://mypage/"$INSTANCE"" SUBDOMAIN"$INSTANCE"="/mysubdomain"

echo $MY_DOMAIN
http://mypage/1

echo $SUBDOMAIN1
/mysubdomain
```

But using `dotenv` it is not working for me. I have the following code:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
var result = dotenv.config({ path: '/path/to/my/env/file' });

console.log(result.parsed);
```

The `console.log` produces the following result:

```
{
  MY_DOMAIN:'http://mypage/"$INSTANCE"'
}
```

So, the env var `INSTANCE` can not be used, the value will be ignored. Are there any solution to solve my issue?

Comment: Discarded by the maintainer: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/159#issuecomment-263137856

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution using [dotenv-expand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand/v/5.1.0) :)